# supporting persistent HTTP connections in my proxy server

Tags: networking, sockets, proxy

I am implementing a HTTP caching proxy server in C++.I am done with most part of it but i am stuck at a point.
What i am doing is creating each thread with a socket to handle each time a request from browser comes. I parse the request, check for its availability in cache and if not found forward it to end www server.In both cases i write the response received on the connected socket. Now the problem is until and unless i close the socket, the browser doesn't assumes the transfer to be complete and waits indefinitely.
This way I can't use a socket for more than one connection, in other words I can't support persistent connections.
Any help will be appreciated..

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What headers are you sending back to the client?

You should be including:

```
Content-Length: ...
Keep-Alive: timeout=..., max=...
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

In particular, the Content-Length header is essential with persistent connections so that the client knows how much data to read.  See [section 8.1.2.1 of RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-44).

Alternatively, if you want to tell the client to break the connection, send:

```
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now the problem is until and unless i close the socket, the browser doesn't assumes the 
>   transfer to be complete and waits indefinitely.

Right.  HTTP 1.1 uses Keep-Alive by default.

> This way I can't use a socket for more than one connection, in other words I can't 
>   support persistent connections.

I'm not sure I understand you, because that persistent connection you have IS a persistent connection.